# Receigen Xcode 10.1 - Unknown type name 'UIDevice'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10.1, receigen

Two of my apps broke after what I assume was a change to Xcode (10.1 - 10B61) or iOS API. Both use Receigen in Obj-C mode and for some reason no longer recognize `UIDevice`.

[image: Unknown type name 'UIDevice']

Here are the imports auto-generated by Receigen:
[image: Imports]

What change to Xcode or the API am I missing?

Comment: Is `UIKit` stated somewhere, since `UIDevice` is present in `UIKit.framework`

Comment: Can you try to uikit

Comment: Turns out Receigen's generation changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receigen released version 4.0.4 which adds the `UIKit/UIKit.h` import. Just make sure you keep in mind the variable type changes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Receigen changed a few things. Previously it didn't import `UIKit/UIKit.h`, but it did import `Foundation/Foundation.h`

Also previously, the method declaration and variable types had more underscores:

```
inline static void FastReceiptCheck_CheckInAppPurchases(NSArray *_inapp_identifiers, FastReceiptCheck_InAppValidateBlock _inapp_block, FastReceiptCheck_CallBackBlock _callback_block)
```

vs

```
inline static void FastReceiptCheck_CheckInAppPurchases(NSArray *_inapp_identifiers, FastReceiptCheckInAppValidateBlock _inapp_block, FastReceiptCheckCallBackBlock _callback_block)
```

I ended up inserting this into my Build Script which adds the `UIKit` import:

`echo '#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>' | cat - "$FILENAME" > temp && mv temp "$FILENAME"`

And changing my method calls

Thanks for the help!